# C# Get Value Tooltip From Website

Tags: c#, html, tooltip

Dear Stackoverflow users,

Currently I am writing a C# application which is getting some data from a website and exports it in a excel sheet. Thankfully all of that is working.

The problem I am having at this moment is that there is an icon on the webpage when you hover your mouse over it shows a table-like element with data in it. And I want to get that data.

In html, it looks like this:

```html
<abbr data-tooltip-id="131711" data-tooltip="order_tip"><img src="/images/printer.png"></abbr>
```

For all the other elements I did the following:

```js
                if (cell.GetAttribute("classname") == "cell-orderid")
                {
                    //run the code
                }
```

But all of the previous data was extracted from the source code.

So I was wondering if there is a way in C# to invoke the hover and get the data that the tooltip displays?

Comment: so the hover triggers some javascript which shows the tooltip?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a javascript or jQuery method.

Comment: You would have to look for that in the site's scripts and download the contents of the callback. Most likely its something like $('abbr').hover(function(){ ... })

Comment: Thank you. I'll will try what you suggested.

Comment: I have looked through the scripts and unfortunately there is nothing that resembles  $('abbr').hover(function(){ ... }).

Comment: Is the site you are downloading from open or some intranet thing? If so can you share a link?

Comment: It is actually an intranet, otherwise I would love to have shared the link. But I might have found something. In the jQuery event listeners under the mouseover I found the following:

Comment: handler: function (e){return typeof b===i||e&&b.event.triggered===e.type?t:b.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem,arguments)}
isAttribute: false
lineNumber: 3
listenerBody: "function (e){return typeof b===i||e&&b.event.triggered===e.type?t:b.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem,arguments)}"
node: abbr
sourceName: "http://10.0.0.163/script/js/jQuery.js"
type: "mouseover"
useCapture: false

Comment: Yeah thats the general jquery library. theres nothing about the source of the tooltip... are there others?

Comment: Try looking for "data-tooltip-id" in the scripts